# react components as destructed export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm building my app using create-react-app. I have folder structure like src/images/icons and in the icons folder I have index.js:

```
import Logo from "./my-logo.svg";

export {
  Logo
}
```

I did that because I can use any icons anywhere like

`import { Logo } from '../images/icon'`

otherwise I would have to do

`import Logo from '../images/icons/my-logo.sv'`

Usually a page won't have 1 or 2 icons, it can be more, I don't want to have super long import. But it doesn't really solve the problem.

The problem is that the index.js within src/images/icon still grow. Every time I add a new icon on my icon folder I have to alter the index.js. Any better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly re-export the default export using named export format, since the default export's name is literally `default`:

```
export {default as Logo} from "./my-logo.svg";
```

That replaces the four lines (ignoring the blank one) you currently have in `index.js`, and avoids having to list `Logo` twice (which is a maintenance hazard).

---

**Note**: This is true for true JavaScript modules, so I'd expect it to work even with a bundler like Webpack or Rollup (which I'm guessing you're using, since you're importing an SVG, which isn't JavaScript functionality but is the kind of thing bundlers often add).

Comment: I don't get it, without index.js in my src/image/icons, how are you going to import the icon ?

Comment: @user3106579 - I may have misunderstood the question. The line above would be in `index.js`. What it does is replace the four lines per icon you currently have with one line per icon. If your goal is to eliminate `index.js` entirely, I'm not sure how you'd do that without having to refer to the icons directly from whatever uses them, which is what I thought you wanted to avoid. Am I solving the wrong problem? :-)

Comment: I see, your one liner code may improve the situation, I hope there is a tool that would able to analyse the files in the folder and automatically update the index.js :)

I found this https://github.com/gajus/create-index

Comment: @user3106579 - Ah, I understand. If this answer isn't useful, let me know and I'll remove it. If you're looking for a way to create the file automatically, I'd update the question to say that explicitly, and to list more about your build environment -- e.g., are you using Webpack, Rollup, Gulp, Grunt, etc.